# Solr Field Alias in Solr Search is not working

Tags: solr

The following link says we can use field aliases like id,price:crazy_price_field etc. I am trying to use it but this is not working.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1205

My Query:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/ee_core/select?indent=on&version=2.2&q=\*%3A\*&fq=%2BinstanceId_index_store%3A217&start=0&rows=10&fl=description_index_store%2Cscore&qt=&wt=json
```

**fl=description_index_store,score** gives correct result with field names **description_index_store** and **score**

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,"QTime": 1,
        "params": {
            "explainOther": "","fl": "description_index_store,score",
            "indent": "on","start": "0","q": "*:*","hl.fl": "","qt": "",
            "wt": "json","fq": "+instanceId_index_store:217","rows": "3",
            "version": "2.2"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 128,"start": 0,"maxScore": 1,
        "docs": [
            {
                "description_index_store": "Apple MacBook - Intel Core 2 Duo",
                "score": 1
            },
            {
                "description_index_store": "Apple MacBook - Intel Core 2 Duo",
                "score": 1
            },
            {
                "description_index_store": "HP Envy - 17.3\" - Intel Core i7",
                "score": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

but when i try to use **alias** like **fl=description:description_index_store,score** in the same query it doesn't return the field.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,"QTime": 0,
        "params": {
            "explainOther": "","fl": "description:description_index_store,score",
            "indent": "on","start": "0","q": "*:*","hl.fl": "","qt": "",
            "wt": "json","fq": "+instanceId_index_store:217","rows": "3",
            "version": "2.2"
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "numFound": 128,"start": 0,"maxScore": 1,
        "docs": [
            {
                "score": 1
            },
            {
                "score": 1
            },
            {
                "score": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to a feature which has been added to the 4.0 version of Solr, not yet released. In fact, within the [fl section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fl) of that wiki page there's an exclamation mark which tells you that the following content (still within the fl section) is available only with Solr 4.0.

The [SOLR-1205 issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1205) has been addressed, together with other improvements, within [SOLR-2444: Update fl syntax to support: pseudo fields, AS, transformers, and wildcards](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2444), which will be released with Solr 4.0. You might want to have a look at the [Solr 4.0 roadmap](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr4.0) to find out when it should be released.